# How to solve: $\arccos(2x)-\arccos(x)=\pi/3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Solve for $x$ the equation $\arccos(2x)-\arccos(x)=\pi/3$.

My [attempt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7s4iytta0k5qy4u/2013-09-27%2014.47.19.jpg) using $\cos(a-b)$. But it gives me a sqrt-expression that I don't know how to handle.

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=acos2x-acosx%3Dpi%2F3#_=_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reduces to an easy quadratic.  First, take the cosine of both sides. Using the cosine addition formula, I get

$$2 x \cdot x + \sqrt{1-4 x^2} \sqrt{1-x^2} = \frac12$$

Manipulate and square both sides to get

$$\left ( 2 x^2-\frac12\right)^2 = (1-4 x^2)(1-x^2) = 1-5 x^2+4 x^4$$

or

$$3 x^2=\frac{3}{4} \implies x = \pm \frac{1}{2}$$

Now plugging in both answers, one sees that only the $-1/2$ result makes sense for the principal branch (or any branch) of the arccos.  Thus, $x=-1/2$.

Comment: Why is it only x=-1/2 that satisfies the equation? I set up:

acos(1) - acos(0.5)= pi/3

and

acos(-1) - acos(-0.5)= pi/3

Now I can get multiple results, since acos(1)=pi/2 and also =3pi/4. How should I think about that?

Comment: @jacob: $\arccos{1}=0$, $\arccos{(1/2)}=\pi/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\arccos\left(2x\right)=\arccos\left(x\right)+\pi/3$. Now take the
cosinus on both sides and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid squaring which often incurs the burden of [extraneous roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions)

Let  $\displaystyle \arccos x=\theta\ \ \ \ (1)\implies x=\cos\theta$

We have $\displaystyle \arccos(2\cos\theta)-\theta=\frac\pi3\implies \arccos(2\cos\theta)=\theta+\frac\pi3\ \ \ \ (2) $

As the  [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of $\arccos$ lies $\in[0,\pi],$

from $(1), 0\le\theta\le\pi$

form $(2), 0\le\theta+\frac\pi3\le\pi\implies -\frac\pi3\le\theta\le\frac{2\pi}3$

So, we need $\displaystyle 0\le \theta\le \frac{2\pi}3\  \ \  \ (3)$

$\displaystyle (2)\implies 2\cos\theta=\cos\left(\frac\pi3+\theta\right)=\cos\frac\pi3\cos\theta-\sin\frac\pi3\sin\theta$

$\displaystyle \implies\frac{\sqrt3}2\sin\theta=\left(\frac12-2\right)\cos\theta$

$\displaystyle \implies\tan\theta=-\sqrt3=\tan\left(-\frac\pi3\right)$

$\displaystyle \implies \theta=n\pi-\frac\pi3$ where $n$ is any integer

From $\displaystyle(3), 0\le n\pi-\frac\pi3\le \frac{2\pi}3\iff 0\le3n-1\le2\implies n=1$

Can you take it from here?